# How can I replace a new line character with a null terminator?

Tags: c

My program is a task list manager... it takes the name, priority, and date of a task using fgets/stdin and puts it in a struct. This is the relevant snippet of my program:

```
task *makeTask(char *name, char *date, char *priority)
{

        task *the_task = malloc(sizeof(task));

        int i;

        the_task->task_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name)));

         for (i=0;name[i] != '\n'; i++) {
                if (name[i] != '\0')
                the_task->task_name[i] = name[i];
        }

        the_task->task_name[i] = '\0';

        //already allocated for in struct
        for (i=0;date[i] != '\n'; i++) {
                if (date[i] != '\0')
                the_task->date_entered[i] = date[i];
        }

        the_task->date_entered[i] = '\0';


        the_task->priority = atoi(priority);
        return the_task; // FILE THIS IN
}
```

Here's the expected output:

```
0: Feed the cats, priority: 5.  Entered 01/01/1111
```

And here's the actual output:

```
0: edsats, priority: 5.  Entered 01/01/1111
```

I've been scratching my head for the past hour trying to fix this problem... what's going on with my code?

Comment: Uhg, my eyes. `(char *)malloc(...` and `sizeof(char)`...

Comment: Hah, I'm innocent of that, honestly. My TA said I needed to future-proof my code for the next two decades. =/

Comment: That's not future-proofing. Rather, it's making your code less maintainable and more error-prone.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name)))`. Realize you don't have enough space to store the null pointer.

Comment: R is complaining because `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1. Also, I would probably write `sizeof(the_task->task_name[0])` if I were worried about future proofing.

Comment: Also, it's best not to include the cast in front of the malloc - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a couple of things:

- You need an extra byte to store the task name, to hold the null terminator
- use `strdup` to allocate memory for a string and copy it into it (for the task name)
- use `strcpy` to copy the date into its preallocated string

I'm also uncertain if you're showing us the code that is actually causing the problem, but try fixing the task name memory block to see if that helps.

Comment: Excellent suggestions, lxop. The code is cleaner and functioning properly now. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't allocate space for `the_task->date_entered`.
2. You need to add `strlen(name) + 1` bytes to account for the null terminator.